# sql union same parameters for two where = how to change it to one parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, union, where-clause

I have this query

```
select last_name, job_id, department_name, country_name, hire_date
     , sysdate, salary
from employees e
   , departments d
   , locations l
   , countries c 
where e.department_id = d.department_id
  and d.location_id = l.location_id 
  and l.country_id = c.country_id 
  and upper(last_name) like upper('%&name%')

union 

select last_name, j.job_id, department_name, country_name, start_date
     , end_date, to_number(null) 
from employees e
  , job_history j
  , departments d
  , locations l
  , countries c 
where j.department_id = d.department_id 
  and d.location_id = l.location_id 
  and l.country_id = c.country_id 
  and j.employee_id = e.employee_id 
  and upper(last_name) like upper('%&name%');
```

as you see on both select in this union we get    'like upper('%&name%')'
is this is way to don't ask it both time but to pass it from first select to second in this union?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can use a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select last_name, job_id, department_name, country_name, hire_date,
             sysdate as thedate, salary, employee_id
      from employees e,
           departments d,
           locations l,
           countries c 
      where e.department_id = d.department_id
            and d.location_id = l.location_id 
            and l.country_id = c.country_id 
            and upper(last_name) like upper('%&name%')
    )
select last_name, job_id, department_name, country_name, hire_date, thedate, salary
from t union 
select last_name, job_id, department_name, country_name, hire_date, thedate, NULL
from t join
     job_history jh
     on jh.employee_id = t.employee_id;
```

The use of `sysdate` makes me think of Oracle, which does support the `with` statement.

By the way, you should learn to use proper join syntax, which uses the `join` keyword in the `from` clause.  There is an example in this query.

Comment: yes it's oracle, and yes both join syntax are proper for Oracle.
Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but I think the answer is "yes".  The entire query (the two `selects` combined with the `union` operator) work as a single transaction.  The symbol substitution of your parameter "&name" will be applied in both places.